# Is there any way to skip importing a particular Clearcase sync packet

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, multisite

There is a problem in importing a packet in Clearcase replica. We researched a lot to resolve the issue, but as per IBM this is a bug in a particular version of clearcase.

So if there is any way to skip importing that particular packet,that would really help us in resolving the sync issue.

Issue : [http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM53060]

Our vob servers are already already on the version which as per above tech note has a fix for the issue, still the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

The [syncreplica documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH5A_7.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.ms_admin.doc/cmd_reference/mu_syncreplica.htm) does mention it "skips" packets only when:

- > the update packet contains changes that depend on other changes that have not yet been imported to this replica.
- Problems were encountered processing an earlier physical packet in a multiple-part logical packet.

> In these cases, syncreplica –import displays an explanatory message.

In other cases, since importing a packet can depends on previous packets being applied, I don't know if that process can allow "skipping" a packet.